# Stopping postfix - are messages queued when postfix is idle?

Tags: centos, email, postfix, services, mail-command

I am running some scans on my server tonight and would like to disable email notifications since there is a chance for a LOT of them to be sent out.

I am planning to issue

```
service postfix stop
```

while the web scan occurs.

If `postfix` is stopped, will mail messages go into a queue and be sent when the service is started again?  If so, is there a way to easily nuke any queued messages?   The messages would be triggered through php's `mail` function, which ordinarily hands off to `postfix`.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP `mail` function will invoke the `sendmail` binary to send a message. So there is not a need for the postfix daemon to be running.

Sendmail will place the email in the maildrop queue. **When postfix starts running**, the `pickup` daemon will pick the message and send it. **When postfix isn't running**, emails stay in maildrop queue <s>forever</s> until they are picked up when postfix runs again.

Resources: [Postfix Architecture Overview](http://www.postfix.org/OVERVIEW.html#receiving)

> Local submissions are received with the Postfix sendmail(1) compatibility command, and are queued in the maildrop queue by the privileged postdrop(1) command. This arrangement even works while the Postfix mail system is not running. The local pickup(8) server picks up local submissions, enforces some sanity checks to protect Postfix, and gives the sender, recipients and message content to the cleanup(8) server.

**If so, is there a way to easily nuke any queued messages**

Yes. Because the email is stored in maildrop queue, you can run `postsuper -d ALL maildrop` to nuke all of them. See [man 1 postsuper](http://www.postfix.org/postsuper.1.html).

```
# postsuper -d ALL maildrop
postsuper: Deleted: 1 message
```

Comment: What file or directory are queued messages stored in? I might want to review some of these prior to nuking all of them.

Comment: See the output of `postconf queue_directory`